# Scanf -Two or more times the user input have to enter

Tags: c, scanf

I have written one C application contains switch statements.When I tried to run the application,it will prompt for options,sometimes when i tried to enter one option the system is not responding,only after 2 or more time I am forced to enter the same option with enter.
Is there any problem in my code?
Am executing the application in my development board ,through Terminal. 
See below my code snippet

```c
#include "TestApp.h"

int main(void) {
BTON = "ON";    // To hold Bluetooth status as ON
BTOFF = "OFF";  // To hold Bluetooth status as OFF
int mainChoice, btChoice, zigChoice; // To select choices
char key, keyMain, c; // To handle continuity of the program
int flag = 0; // To handle continuity of the program
btstatus = "OFF";
puts("!!! Test App!!!\n");
do {

    printf("\nMain  Menu: Enter your choice\n"
            "1.Bluetooth Test\n"
            "2.Zigbee Test\n"
            "3.Brightness Test\n");
    scanf("%d", &mainChoice);
    switch (mainChoice) {

    case 1:
        flag = 1;

        do {

            printf("Enter your choice for Bluetooth :\n"
                    "1. Turn on bluetooth\n"
                    "2. Turn on visibility\n"
                    "3. Set passkey\n"
                    "4. Scan bluetooth device\n"
                    "5. Display bluetooth configuration\n"
                    "6. Reset Passkey\n"
                    "7. Turn off visibility\n"
                    "8. Turn off bluetooth\n");
            scanf("%d", &btChoice);
            bluetoothTest(btChoice);

            do {
                printf(
                    "Do u want to continue with bluetooth test? (y/n) \n");               
                while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
                    ;
                key = getchar();

                if (key != 'y' && key != 'n') {
                    printf("Invalid choice\n");
                }
            } while (key != 'y' && key != 'n');
        } while (key == 'y');
        break;

    case 2:
        flag = 1;

        do {

            printf("Enter your choice for Zigbee :\n"
                                    "1. To Enable Zigbee Module\n"
                                    "2. Display Firmware version\n"
                                    "3. Display network information\n"
                                    "4. Disassociate from PAN\n"
                                    "5. Establish PAN\n"
                                    "6. Scan for PAN\n"
                                    "7. Join network\n"
                                    "8. Scan Network \n"
                                    "9. Broadcast message\n");
            scanf("%d", &zigChoice);
            zigbeeTest(zigChoice);

            do {
                printf("Do u want to continue with zigbee test? (y/n) \n");
                while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
                    ;
                key = getchar();

                if (key != 'y' && key != 'n') {
                    printf("Invalid choice\n");
                }
            } while (key != 'y' && key != 'n');
        } while (key == 'y');
        break;
    case 3:
        flag = 1;
        do {
            brightnessTest();

            do {
                printf(
                        "Do u want to continue with brightness test? (y/n) \n");
                while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
                    ;
                key = getchar();
                if (key != 'y' && key != 'n') {
                    printf("Invalid choice\n");
                }
            } while (key != 'y' && key != 'n');
        } while (key == 'y');
        break;

    default:
        printf("\n Invalid choice\n");
        break;
    }
    do {
        printf("Do u want to continue  Test App? (y/n) \n");
        if (flag == 1) {
            while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
                ;
        }

        keyMain = getchar();
        if (keyMain != 'y' && keyMain != 'n') {
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }

    } while (keyMain != 'y' && keyMain != 'n');

    if (keyMain == 'n') {
        break;
    }
} while (keyMain == 'y');
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }

void bluetoothTest(int option) {

switch (option) {
case 1:
    turnBluetooth(BTON);

    break;
case 2:
    setVisibility(BTON);

    break;
case 3:
    setPasskey();
    break;
case 4:
    scanBTDevice();
    break;
case 5:
    displayBTConfiguration();
    break;
case 6:
    resetPasskey();
    break;
case 7:
    setVisibility(BTOFF);
    break;
case 8:
    turnBluetooth(BTOFF);
    break;
default:
    printf("\n Invalid choice\n");
    break;

}

 }
 void zigbeeTest(int option) {
  switch (option) {
    case 1:
        printf("\n Zigbee Module Enabled!!!! \n");
        zigbeeEnable();

        break;
    case 2:
        displayFirmwareVersion();

        break;
    case 3:
        displayNetworkInfo();

        break;
    case 4:
        disAssociateFromPan();

        break;
    case 5:
        establishPan();

        break;
    case 6:
        scanForPan();

        break;
    case 7:
        joinNetwork();

        break;
    case 8:
        scanNetwork();

        break;
    case 9:
        broadcastMessage();

        break;

    default:
        printf("\n Invalid choice\n");
        break;

}

}

 void brightnessTest() {
float brightval;
printf("Enter brightness value from 0 to 10  :\n  ");
scanf("%f", &brightval);
setBrightness(brightval);
}
```

Comment: "I have written one java application" Really java?

Comment: what was the input that didn't work?

Comment: When it prompts for Enter you choice,I added 1.Some times it will execute the functionality in 1st case.But sometimes i have to enter 1 more than once.

Comment: Sorry mistaken,its c

Comment: @DRD Please post a shortened version of the code that reproduces the problem. Your problem is with an extra `getchar()` somewhere.

Comment: Minor: use `int c` rather than `char c` for ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)` to work correctly.

Comment: Mixing `scanf("%d"` with `getchar()` is certainly the issue.  Create separate function to read a number and consume the_ entire_ line.  Code's `while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))` somewhat does this, but it is not needed in `switch (mainChoice) case 3.`

Comment: But Char c value is accepting y/n value.That is not integer .Other options are integer.

Comment: please help me to resolve this